# Responsive Button using jquery and css

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design

I have a div with a heading using  and i have a Vertical Navigation menu in same div.
To make it responsive i use media query and "Display:none and position:abolute" to Navigation Container.
it works perfectly fine till this step.

NOW what i want is that. when i click this heading  the the Navigation menu appears and when i click a Link on the Navigation Menu disappears means the menu itself become"Display:none"

I used .toggle() jquery to achieve this.
when this works perfectly fine.

but problem is that i want that this .toggle() function not to work when the width of window is more then 980px;

```
<h2 id="heading"><span>Office<span class="blue">Managnment</span></span></h2>

<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#p">P</a></li>
    <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#n">N</a></li>
    <li><a href="#lb">L</a></li>
    <li><a href="#a">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="#r">R</a></li>
    <li><a href="#p">P</a></li>
</ul>
```

and javascript

```
$(function () {
    $("#heading").click(function () {
        $("#list").toggle();
    });
    $("#list").click(function () {
        $("#list").toggle('hide');
    });
});
```

and yes i tried if statement to execute this code only when the width is less then 980px but problem is that it only check for width when the page load. i.e if the window is less then 980 on load. script works fine. but when window is more then 980 on load the script do not work even on resizing it to less then 980px.

i dont understand how to achieve this. mainly problem in choosing the condition for the the if else statement.

1. load the window and check the width

   - if it is less then 980px execute the script
   - if it is more then 980 do not execute the script.
2. on resize of the window check the new width

   - if it was more then 980 previously

     - check if the width increased. if it is increased do nothing(script should not work)
     - check if the width is now less then 980 . **START the script.**Script should work now.
   - if it was less then 980 previosly.

     - check if the width increased more then 980. if it is increased **STOP the script.** it should not work now
     - check if the width is now less then 980 . Do nothing. Script should work now.

**IN SHORT turn on the toggle function when width less then 980px. and turn the toggle off and set to show when width is more then 980px.**

**I figured it out as below. It works, but sometimes when i resize slowly it behave strangely.**

```
            var $window = $(window),
                ONLOADtoggleEnabled = false,
                smallscreenbefore = false;

            $window.on('resize', function() {

                if (smallscreenbefore == false && $window.width() > 1220) {


                } else if( smallscreenbefore == false && $window.width() < 1220) {

                    $( "#Tablist" ).hide(400);
                    $( "#heading" ).click(function() {
                                                                $( "#Tablist" ).toggle(400);                    
                            }); 
                            $( "#Tablist" ).click(function() {
                                                                $( "#Tablist" ).toggle(400);                    
                            });
                            smallscreenbefore = true;   

                }
                else if(smallscreenbefore == true && $window.width() > 1220 ) {

                        $( "#heading" ).unbind('click');
                            $( "#Tablist" ).unbind('click');
                            $( "#Tablist" ).show(400);
                            smallscreenbefore = false;

                }
                else if(smallscreenbefore == true && $window.width() < 1220 ) {

                            smallscreenbefore = false;

                }
            });




            var $window = $(window);
            $window.on('load', function() {

                if ($window.width() < 1220) {

                            $( "#heading" ).click(function() {
                                                                $( "#Tablist" ).toggle(400);                    
                            }); 
                            $( "#Tablist" ).click(function() {
                                                                $( "#Tablist" ).toggle(400);                    
                            });

                            smallscreenbefore = true;

                }
                else if($window.width() > 1220) {

                    smallscreenbefore = false;
                } 
            });
```

Comment: Can u add http://jsfiddle.net for the same

Comment: turn on the toggle function when width less then 980px. and turn the toggle off when width is more then 980px.

Comment: You know this `$("#list").toggle('hide')` basically means `$("#list").toggle(400)`. The string does nothing special unless it's "fast" or "slow". Want proof? http://jsbin.com/afebep/1/edit

Comment: well it doesnt matter to me. even if i skip this "hide" input. code will not be effected much. thanks by the way

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/atleyvirdee/srm6p/2/ @dreamweiver   i did not added css as it is not needed in here. i just want that this function only work when the width is less then some defined width.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the resize event on the window and then use the width to decide what you want to do. I suppose something like this should work:

```
var MAX_WIDTH = 980,
    $window = $(window),
    toggleEnabled = false;

$window.on('resize', function() {
    // Check window width and check if toggle isn't already enabled
    if ($window.width() < MAX_WIDTH) {
        // Check if toggle isn't enabled yet
        if (!toggleEnabled) {
            // Use on() to add eventListener
            $("#heading").on('click', function () {
                $("#list").toggle();
            });
            $("#list").on('click', function () {
                $("#list").toggle('hide');
            });

            toggleEnabled = true;
        }
    } else if (toggleEnabled) {
        // Use off() to remove eventListener
        $("#heading").off('click');
        $("#list").off('click');

        // Show the list
        $('#list').show();

        toggleEnabled = false;
    }

    $('#output').text('Width: ' + $window.width() + ', toggleEnabled: ' + toggleEnabled);
});

// You can trigger the resize event at the start to set the initial state of the menu
$window.trigger('resize');
```

Working version with your list: http://jsfiddle.net/srm6p/3/

Comment: as you see above i used 
    $("#list").click(function () {
        $("#list").toggle('hide');
    });
this function to enable the toggle on click.. HOW will i disable it? can you please tell me the code to disable toggle function?

Comment: do you know ,how to disable it? diable the toggle function or disable the click function.

Comment: click() is just a shortcut for on('click', function). You can use on() to add the listener and use off() to remove the listener. http://api.jquery.com/on/